# Socket Connection to node server from https gives mixed content error

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I have a website running on https and as part of new feature I created a nodejs+socket.io based conversation server.

I decided to host conversation server on separate AWS instance. 
When I try to make socket connection from my main website (running on https) to conversation server (running on AWS static IP instance like http://123.123.45.56) then it does not establish socket connection properly and browser shows following error logged to console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mydomain' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://123.123.45.56/socket.io/?payload=asdfkasdla'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

This is how I make the connection node server:

```
io.connect(chatServerURL,{query: "payload=" + encryptedPayload,secure: false});
```

On conversation server I am routing all the traffic coming on port 80 with the route /socket.io to locally node server port and server as follows:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

What should I do to make it work?
I don't have domain to use just for chat server and then assign ssl to that domain. I know that should not be the way to make it work.

What is the solution to it?

Comment: Broadly speaking, the solution is not to make a request to an insecure `http:` or `ws:` websocket service (instead you must connect to an `https:` or `wss:` service). How you go about making your existing service use `https:`/`wss:` (or finding a new service that does) depends on the particulars of the service you're connecting to (or your criteria for selecting a new service with the support you need). The other solution is to make your top-level page insecure, and stop serving your current page via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone in the future for right approach. 
The way to do this is to send socket connection to same server i.e the one on running on https and then use reverse proxy there to proxy socket request to different machine running on http (running the node+socket.io server).

On Apache server I need to enable modules `proxy` and `proxy_http` and add these directives in apache virtual host configuration:

```
ProxyPass /socket.io/ http://123.45.56.67/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ http://123.45.56.67/socket.io
```

There are lot resources online for that, I was just unaware of this proxying thing. 
That's the way to do it.